# Python kivy, enlarging an image in

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

In python kivy, I have an FloatLayout for my self.root, later i add an Image to it with a pos_hint.

```
self.avatar.image = Image(source=self.avatar.current_images[0], keep_ratio=False, pos_hint={'center_x':0.5, 'center_y': 0.5})
```

I then add it to root on startup.

I want to be able to increase the image size with a click of a button, but it always gets too big.

I've tried many things such as even increasing it by a tiny amount like so

```
self.avatar.image.size_hint = [originalW*1.005, originalH*1.005]
```

I've had many suggestion which iv'e tried, such as scale, or updating self.avatar.image.size or changing keep_ratio.

None of this works, either it doesn't change at all, or it only gets way too big via a tiny increment (off the screen) or if I am modifying the .size property then the image never changes size visibly.

So my question for you is, what is the normal process for increasing an image size in a floatlayout? Is this even possible? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

My confusion was that size and size_hint behave differently, size is in pixels and size_hint is a % of the parent widget.

When I was changing pixel values it was maintaining ratio and not changing, when i was changing size_hint by same amount it was skyrocketing because it should be a % value.

In summary:

size = pixels
size_hint = percent